# jqplot chartline not showing even when css is loaded

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I have some problems with JQplot showing 2 lines in a graph.
The graph and data gets loaded, but the lines do not appear.
I'm sure that i load the correct css files.
I can't demonstrate it at jsfiddle since, it appears only to happen on that specific page.

Sorry for my bad english.

Link to the page causing trouble
http://wot.brantje.com/stats/brantje

Comment: You have to use DateAxisRenderer to render your graph. then the lines would come up. Please refer the jqplot website for references

Comment: Can you post it as an answer so i can accept it? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `DateAxisRenderer` to render your graph. then the lines would come up. Please refer the [jqplot website](http://www.jqplot.com) for references